# plot points, each iteration, over a "baseline" plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some points (different for every iteration) on an existing plot (say, baseline plot). For every iteration, I'd like to add to the baseline plot only the points associated to the current iteration.

On the contrary, my code still keeps points of previous iterations.

```py
# random values. baseline points
x_fix = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y_fix = [5,4,0,7,3,6,4,5]

# define baseline plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
graph = ax.scatter(x_fix, y_fix, c='black')

def update(asdf):
    global aaa
    x = [i[0] for i in aaa]
    y = [i[1] for i in aaa]
    ax.scatter(x, y, c='red')

arr = [[[3,5], [4,5], [7,6]],
       [[3,7], [4,5]],
       [[3,5], [4,7], [7,6]],
       [[3,5], [7,6], [8,8], [9,9], [3,1]]]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    aaa = arr[i]    # points to be plotted at i-th iteration
    animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=1)
    plt.show(block=False)
    plt.pause(1)
```

I'd like, for each iteration, only the  points in `aaa` to be plotted on the baseline plot.

Comment: You can use a loop ***or*** FuncAnimation, but not both, and especially not one inside the other.

Comment: Thank you for the answear. How can I deal with it, than?

Comment: Start by looking at one of the hundreds of examples that are available on stackoverflow, the matplotlib documentation or other blogs. Then adapt it to your needs. If you then find a problem, update your question.